# File binding in WebApi controller not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm trying to upload files from Angular to .NET Core WebAPI and somethings seems wrong with my code:

```
    [HttpPost("UploadImage")]
    public IActionResult UploadImage([FromForm]ICollection<IFormFile> formFiles)
    {
        var picture = new Picture();
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        ...
    }
```

The parameter formFiles is not null but doesn't contains any file (count = 0) but in the `Request.Form.Files` the files are here and I can get the data with `OpenReadStream()`
If I omit the `FromForm` attribute, I had the same, if I rename the parameter `formFiles`, same result.

How can I do automatic binding instead of access to Request property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done the same thing recently, my experience was the same.

The only way to get access to the files is through the `Request.Form.Files` property, no arguments to the method will work. Note that you *can* mock the `Request` property for your unit tests, so its not as bad as it seems.

UPDATE: As of .NET Core 2.0 this seems to be working again

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but can't seem to find out where to get `Request.Form.Files`.. see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800814/upload-file-to-webapi-controller-not-working)